# Rights of access to a landlocked plot - le droit de désenclavement

Tags: france, real-property

I have a question about Rights of Access in France.

I've read that landlocked land can be accessed via 'the shortest possible route' but I'm not clear whether that always means 'shortest distance to public highway', or whether it can mean 'shortest distance from another (non-adjacent) parcel of land under the same ownership'.

Any thoughts?

Comment: I've heard of this situation arising in North Dakota, where farmers are, or were, considered to have a right to drive on roads owned by other farmers to reach the public highway (often a gravel road).